# I can't install postgresql-simple on haskell

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, haskell, cabal

When I write this command: **cabal install postgres-simple** or **cabal install postgresql-simple**

This error appears:

**cabal: Error: some packages failed to install: postgresql-libpg-0.9.4.2 failed during the configure step. The exception was: ExitFailure 1
postgresql-simple-0.6.2 depends on postgresql-libpg-0.9.4.2 which failed to install.**

I tried on windows and Ubuntu, the same error appears.

Comment: `postgres` itself needs to be installed. Also, you'll save yourself some headache if you install and manage dependencies with `stack`.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment notes, you need to have postgres already installed on your system.